# want to select mean of daily values for each month

Tags: mysql

I have table reg_data 3 I entered data one value per one day. I want to select mean of that value(sum of value/no of days) but rainfall I need sumation, for one month..... but this code does not work properly.

```
SELECT 
    year(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y'))as year,
    month(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y'))as month,
    Avg(sunshine_hrs) as sunshine_hrs,
    AVG(max_temp) as max_temp
    sum(rainfall) as rainfall
    avg(evep) as evep 
    avg(min_temp) as min_temp
FROM
    reg_data3
GROUP BY
    year(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y')),
    month(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y'));

CREATE TABLE `reg_data3` (
 `date` varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',
 `time` time NOT NULL,
 `rainfall` float default NULL,
 `evep` float default NULL,
 `max_temp` float default NULL,
 `min_temp` float default NULL,
 `sunshine_hrs` float default NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Can you please post a couple of lines from the table?

Comment: The AVG function returns the mean.  What do you think AVG(rainfall) would return to you?

Comment: Please explain specifically how *...this code does not work properly...*. Do you get an error? Does the outcome differ from expected? If so then what is your expected outcome? Provide some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add commas after each field specified in the query except for the last one. Like this:

```
SELECT 
    year(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y'))as year,
    month(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y'))as month,
    Avg(sunshine_hrs) as sunshine_hrs,
    AVG(max_temp) as max_temp,
    sum(rainfall) as rainfall,
    avg(evep) as evep,
    avg(min_temp) as min_temp
FROM
    reg_data3
GROUP BY
    year(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y')),
    month(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y'));
```